# Calculating R combinations from CSV file

Tags: r, combinatorics

I have a CSV file which contains about 400 values ranging from 10 000 to 50 000.

I want to calculate what combinations of selected values, for example 100, 150, 200,250 correspond to values in CSV file.

Is it possible to do it in R?

So this is part of the data:

```
1359.214844
1604.558594
1701.759766
1761.083984
1792.990234
1926.248047
1958.144531
2086.373047
2114.501953
2142.542969
2204.325621
2216.468750
2229.136719
2286.894531
2302.847656
2379.826172
2395.039063
2467.578125
2610.802734
2797.929688
2812.916016
2838.947266
2979.498047
3122.171875
3163.671875
3457.794922
3809.228516
3826.058594
3952.609375
3983.210938
4102.996094
```

Second data set is (`146.058, 203.193, 162.053, 291.095`)
I need possible combinations of second data set that corresponds to values in the first on. For example 291*2+162*5+203*4 = 2204.

Comment: Sounds possible, but would be great to have a specific example to understand 100% what you want and also have some data to build a process with.

Comment: I added data to the question. I manually added 2204 as I am unsure if there will be real combinations in this small sample.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to take me through the logic here. You have 4 values in your second dataset. How do you define "correspond to values in CSV"? How did you work out  291*2+162*5+203*4 ? And where are the decimal places? Do you ignore them, or you round them? Looks like you mean a linear combination of 291*a + 203*b + 162*c + 291*d = a value from CSV file.

Comment: Yes I mean linear combination of 146a + 291b +203c +162d +291e= value from CSV. a,b,c,d,e can be zero.

It is ok to ignore decimal values as I only need approximate combinations. I will manually see if they make logical sense in terms of what I expect.

Comment: Ok, I have something in mind and I'll try to post it later when I get some free time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be alternative ways to do that, like a loop that checks a specific combination at iteration `i` and decides to keep it or ignore it, but I prefer not to use loops when possible.

```
library(dplyr)

dt = read.table(text = "1359.214844
                1604.558594
                1701.759766
                1761.083984
                1792.990234
                1926.248047
                1958.144531
                2086.373047
                2114.501953
                2142.542969
                2204.325621
                2216.468750
                2229.136719
                2286.894531
                2302.847656
                2379.826172
                2395.039063
                2467.578125
                2610.802734
                2797.929688
                2812.916016
                2838.947266
                2979.498047
                3122.171875
                3163.671875
                3457.794922
                3809.228516
                3826.058594
                3952.609375
                3983.210938
                4102.996094")

# change column name and round values
names(dt) = "value"
dt$value = round(dt$value)

# give the manual values (assuming they are 4 values)
manual_values = c(146.058, 203.193, 162.053, 291.095)

# round values
manual_values = round(manual_values)


# get the maximum coefficient to investigate
coeff = ceiling(max(dt$value) / min(manual_values))


expand.grid(v1 = manual_values[1],  ## create all combinations of coefficients and keep your values
            v2 = manual_values[2],
            v3 = manual_values[3],
            v4 = manual_values[4],
            coeff1 = 0:coeff,
            coeff2 = 0:coeff,
            coeff3 = 0:coeff,
            coeff4 = 0:coeff) %>%
  mutate(value = v1*coeff1+v2*coeff2+v3*coeff3+v4*coeff4) %>%  ## calculate the value from each combination
  inner_join(dt, by="value")  ## join info from your initial values


## sample of the first 10 rows of the result :

#      v1  v2  v3  v4 coeff1 coeff2 coeff3 coeff4 value
# 1   146 203 162 291      3     10      0      0  2468
# 2   146 203 162 291      7     12      0      0  3458
# 3   146 203 162 291      9     13      0      0  3953
# 4   146 203 162 291      7      3      1      0  1793
# 5   146 203 162 291     22      3      1      0  3983
# 6   146 203 162 291     15      4      1      0  3164
# 7   146 203 162 291      4      5      1      0  1761
# 8   146 203 162 291      0     11      1      0  2395
# 9   146 203 162 291      4     11      1      0  2979
# 10  146 203 162 291      2     14      2      0  3458
```

So, the first line of the output tells you that the combination 3*146 + 10*203 equals 2468, which is a value that exists in your initial dataset (CSV).

If you spot any bugs, or you need any clarifications let me know and I can update my answer.

A small improvement could be to replace the last `inner_join` with `filter(value %in% dt$value)`. I don't think there's any reason to join when you can get the same output by using a filtering command.

---

For your other objective (specified in the comments) try this:

```
library(dplyr)

dt = read.table(text = "1359.214844
                1604.558594
                1701.759766
                1761.083984
                1792.990234
                1926.248047
                1958.144531
                2086.373047
                2114.501953
                2142.542969
                2204.325621
                2216.468750
                2229.136719
                2286.894531
                2302.847656
                2379.826172
                2395.039063
                2467.578125
                2610.802734
                2797.929688
                2812.916016
                2838.947266
                2979.498047
                3122.171875
                3163.671875
                3457.794922
                3809.228516
                3826.058594
                3952.609375
                3983.210938
                4102.996094")

# change column name and round values
names(dt) = "value"
dt$value = round(dt$value)

# give the manual values (assuming they are 4 values)
manual_values = c(146.058, 203.193, 162.053, 291.095)

# get the maximum coefficient to investigate
coeff = ceiling(max(dt$value) / min(manual_values))


expand.grid(v1 = manual_values[1],  ## create all combinations of coefficients and keep your values
            v2 = manual_values[2],
            v3 = manual_values[3],
            v4 = manual_values[4],
            coeff1 = 0:3,
            coeff2 = 5:coeff,
            coeff3 = 5:coeff,
            coeff4 = 0:3) %>%
  mutate(SUM = v1*coeff1+v2*coeff2+v3*coeff3+v4*coeff4) %>%  ## calculate the value of each combination
  tbl_df()                          ## only for printing top 10 rows


#         v1      v2      v3      v4 coeff1 coeff2 coeff3 coeff4      SUM
#      (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl)  (int)  (int)  (int)  (int)    (dbl)
# 1  146.058 203.193 162.053 291.095      0      5      5      0 1826.230
# 2  146.058 203.193 162.053 291.095      1      5      5      0 1972.288
# 3  146.058 203.193 162.053 291.095      2      5      5      0 2118.346
# 4  146.058 203.193 162.053 291.095      3      5      5      0 2264.404
# 5  146.058 203.193 162.053 291.095      0      6      5      0 2029.423
# 6  146.058 203.193 162.053 291.095      1      6      5      0 2175.481
# 7  146.058 203.193 162.053 291.095      2      6      5      0 2321.539
# 8  146.058 203.193 162.053 291.095      3      6      5      0 2467.597
# 9  146.058 203.193 162.053 291.095      0      7      5      0 2232.616
# 10 146.058 203.193 162.053 291.095      1      7      5      0 2378.674
# ..     ...     ...     ...     ...    ...    ...    ...    ...      ...
```

You can save this result table as a data frame and continue your process as you like.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried implementing it but for this specific task it does not give what I need.

Do you think it would be possible to just take manual_values and get sum of each of different combinations.

For example  coeff1 = 0:3;   coef= 5-29, coeff3=5-29, coeff4= 0:3


and the results give sum of each combination insted of value search.

Comment: Do you mean the last column should be `SUM` instead of `value`? That would be easy. Why it doesn't give what you need? DId you spot the mistake so I can correct it? If you force coeff1 and coeff3 to be from 0 to 3 you might lose combinations that work. Is that OK?

Comment: There is no mistake in the code it is just that my value number is too high so it can't run. And also upon inspecting with smaller number of values it seems that finding combination with closest sum to each value would work better in my specific case.

coeff1 and coeff4 can be from 0:3  as I am currently not interested in combinations where they are higher.

Comment: Now I got it. Calculating all combinations to find which ones exist is a "problem" as it will be slow if you have a high `value` or if you have many `manual-values`. If you can restrict the coefficients you make the process faster. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes. And also if I work only with manual_values I can keep decimals and get sum of their combinations, and then I can manually compare for hits in the value file.